# XML formatter in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display an XML response sent from a web service in a textarea or pre tag prettifying it with node collapse and expand buttons (like the  ones we see when we open XML file in chrome). I was able to align XML using some plug ins but the expand collapse bar is not there. I have already used one such json viewer for json formatting which do provide the expand-collapse button.

Answer (score 0):

try this

An extensible jQuery plugin to pretty-print or minify text in XML, JSON, CSS and SQL formats

https://plugins.jquery.com/format/

Comment: I tried this before, its not creating the expand-collapse button